# What is the importance of target in makefile?

Tags: makefile

I am learning how to create `makefile` on a Linux distro. 
I am using the following code (I know it can be written in a small form, but the long form is intentional) to properly understand the behavior of `makefile`

```
test: test.o
        cc -o test test.o 
test.o: test.c
        cc -c test.c
clean:
        rm test.o
```

Now, when I use `make` and `make clean` in the shell, they are working as intended.

However, I want to know the importance of `target` in `makefile`. Hence, started by changing `test.o: test.c` line to `test2.o: test.c` and typed `make` in the shell; my initial guess was that there would be a file in my `home` directory called `test2.o`, but that's not the case, I still see `test.o` being created again.

So, the above behavior begs my question, what is the important of `target` component in `makefile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr**

**Your `test2.o` rule is never executed. `test.o` is created by make's *implicit rule*.**

---

Let's take this apart.

```
test.o: test.c
        cc -c test.c
```

This is a **rule**.

The general syntax for a rule is:

```
targets : prerequisites
        recipee
```

So, `test.o` is the **target**, and `test.c` the **prerequisite**.

If:

- the target (file) does not exist, or
- (one of) the prerequisite(s) is *newer* than the target,

the **recipee** is executed (which should, but does not have to, *create* the target).

So, let's look at your Makefile:

```
test: test.o
        cc -o test test.o 
test.o: test.c
        cc -c test.c
```

When you say `make test`, you want to create the target `test`. This target has `test.o` as prerequisite.

For `test.o` exists another rule, with `test.c` as prerequisite. So *that* rule gets checked and executed first (compiling your source to object code), before the `test` prerequisite is checked, and the recipee run if required (linking your object code to executable format).

---

> Hence, started by changing `test.o: test.c` line to `test2.o: test.c` and typed make in the shell; my initial guess was that there would be a file in my home directory called `test2.o`, but that's not the case, I still see `test.o` being created again.

No target has a `test2.o` prerequisite, and you did not ask for that to be build specifically (`make test2.o`), so the recipee for `test2.o` is never executed.

But `test` still has `test.o` as a prerequisite. As there is no explicit rule for a target of that name in your Makefile, `make` substitutes it with its [implicit rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Implicit-Rules) for creating a `.o` file from an existing `.c` file...

Answer (score 1):

The 'target' is the file which Make checks to determine whether it needs to execute the commands associated with the target at all.

I.e. if you change `test.o: test.c` to `test2.o: test.c`, Make sees that `test2.o` does not exist and hence executes the command `cc -c test.c` -- which still only creates `test.o`. Hence, if you re-run make, you will see that the compiler is executed *again* because `test.o` still does not exist.

In the original version, `test.o: test.c`, the compiler will only be executed if `test.o` does not exist, or if the modification time of `test.c` is newer than that of `test.o`.

Comment: In 5th line , isn't it supposed to be `test2.o` instead of `test.o`?

Answer (score 1):

The target becomes available in the commands section as a variable `$@`, which can be used to define what gets built.

In your makefile you had:

```
test2.o: test.c
    cc -c test.c
```

Because you didn't tell the compiler what the output would be as part of the `cc` command, it created `test.o` from `test.c`, which is the default behaviour. If you run `cc -c file.c` it will generate `file.o` by default.

You need to specify the destination file as part of the commands run for generating the target, so:

```
test2.o: test.c
    cc -c test.c -o $@
```

Would cause the compiler to generate the `test2.o` file appropriately.

At a fundamental level, a makefile is nothing more that a set of targets, dependencies for the targets and the sets of commands for making those targets. You have to ensure that as part of the build process, the final product from a set of commands is the target in order to have a properly functioning makefile.

The compiler doesn't know anything about the fact that it's being run in the makefile.

There are a bunch of automatic rules, pre-created by the default make system. These include rules for making `.o` files from `.c` files - it knows that it needs to compile a file using the following rule and commands:

```
%.o: %.c
#  commands to execute (built-in):
        $(COMPILE.c) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

where `COMPILE.c`:

```
COMPILE.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) -c
```

and `OUTPUT_OPTION` is:

```
OUTPUT_OPTION = -o $@
```

`CC` defaults to `cc`, `CFLAGS` defaults to empty, `CPPFLAGS` defaults to empty and `TARGET_ARCH` defaults to empty. You can see these definitions using `make -p`

So the resulting command is:

```
cc -c -o $@ $<
```

Where `$@` is the name of the target and `$<` is the first item in the list of dependencies. This pattern matches all target files called `<something>.o` where there is an *existing* file called `<something>.c`. If there's a request to build `test.o` as a target then it will compile a file called `test.c`, because that file exists and matches these rules.

Answer (score 0):

The default output file from `cc -c test.c` is `test.o`. If you want it to create `test2.o`, you need to tell it explicitly:

test2.o: test.c
        cc -o test2.o -c test.c

`cc` doesn't know anything about the `makefile` or what target it's being run from.

The importance of targets is that they're used for finding all the dependencies. So the first rule in your makefile says that `test` is dependent on `test.o`: before you can create `test`, you first need to create `test.o`, and if `test.o` has changed, you need to rebuild `test`.

The commands below the target are expected to do whatever it takes to create the target. But you have to code that explicitly (although there are some macros that can automatically substitute targets and dependencies into the command line -- these are mostly useful when the target contains a wildcard pattern).